# How to authenticate inside C# Web API with Google Authentication?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-authentication

I am developing a C# Web Api (.NET Framework) and would like to use in parallel the AAD authentication (already working correctly) and Google Authentication. This means, my clients (javascript or just Postman) should fetch the token, include it in the Authorization header (Bearer token) and be able to execute the API methods.

However, it seems that the token I am generating with Postman is not accepted by my C# Web Api. I am always getting a HTTP 401. The AAD (Windows Azure Active Directory) works seamlessly.

Using a C# Web Api (.Net Framework 4.6.1), including Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google Nuget package v.4.0.1.

I have created the Oauth client on the google developer console, got my client ID and client secret. Also I have set up the redirect URI there.

I am using Postman Oauth2 authorization, setting following parameters:

- Grant type: implicit
- Callback URL: my url
- AUth URL: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth
- Client ID: 65xxxxxmyclientid.apps.googleusercontent.com
- scope: openid email profile

Then I can log in with my google account, give consent to use the scopes, and am getting the token like this:

Access Token
ya29.Gls7....

This token is then sent as Authorization header like "Bearer ya29.Gls7...."

Startup.Auth

```cs
 public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
                 new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
                 {
                     Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
                     TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                     {
                         ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]
                     },
                 });

            app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
            {
                ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleClientId"],
                ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleClientSecret"],
            });
        }
```

ValuesController

```cs
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
  [Authorize]
        // GET api/values/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }
}
```

Every time I call the API using Postman, I am getting a 401, even though the bearer token is included in the request authorization header.

`HTTP GET https://localhost:44385/api/values/1`

Edit: There is no custom code from my side which would validate the token. I assumed that is being done automatically by the library. In fact, this is done automatically for AAD tokens, but not in the case of Google Oauth.

I expect to get inside the code of the controller method, having at least the identity name set with the google account name/email.

What am I missing to be authenticated inside my controller method with google account?

Comment: What/where/how is the Google OAuth Access Token being validated in your code? I assume that you are using Google OAuth and passing the token in the bearer header from your client code to your backend. At some point, your backend code needs to validate the token. More details are required in your question (edit instead of posting a comment).

Comment: @JohnHanley I have added some information in the edited question. Thank you.

Comment: You need to enable cookies plus enable bearer tokens. This article will help you with an actual code example. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/external-authentication-services

Comment: I actually went through this tutorial you sent. In this case the users are saved in a database of the Web API, and the bearer token is generated from the (cookie?) claims inside the very web API. My goal is however to have a standalone web API which would accept the bearer tokens coming from other clients without any DB or cookie storage. It that possible at all?

Comment: Sure that is possible, but I would not do it. Web servers are stateless by design. You need something to store state which is often a database. Without cookie storage, the client will need to authenticate every request or include the access token with every request. The client should not have access to the access token. The client should just be sending a session ID, stored in a cookie which your backend uses to locate the access tokens, etc.

Comment: Update for my last comment. I was thinking webbrowser/webserver. For service-to-service using access tokens is fine. I think you need to enable `app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);`